# Finding the Cartesian equation of a half line of form arg(z - a - bi) = π/2

Tags: complex-numbers

For an argument form of a half line where
$$ arg(z - a - bi) = π/2 $$
I can see that the cartesian equation will be 
$$ x = a $$
As a line of angle π/2 radians will be vertical.

How do I best show the working for this? Do I simply say, tan(π/2) is undefined and will result in a vertical line, or can I say that $$ tan(π/2) = 1/0 $$ as $$ tan(x) = sin(x)/cos(x) $$
Then from this I get the lines of working:
$$ (y-b)/(x-a) = 1/0 \\
x-a = 0 \\
x = a $$
But then this could also be rearranged to give y = ∞

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that $\arg(w)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we require that $$\Re(w)=0$$ and $$\Im(w)>0$$

So in this case, we have $x-a=0$ and $y-b>0$